# Adding a credit card to Paypal - internal error "We are not able to process your request. Please try again later"

Tags: paypal

Problem: When I try to add a credit card on PayPal, I get the error message:

> Internal Error. We are not able to process your request. Please try again later.

On Internet Explorer this happens as soon as I start to add a credit card.  On Chrome the same message happens after entering my credit card details.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, in case this helps anyone.  I called Paypal for help and they solved the problem by directing me to a simpler page, which wasn't affected by whatever technical issue caused the original error:

```
https://paypal.com/creditcard

(NOTE: PROCEED WITH CAUTION. At the risk of stating the obvious, you should never follow a
link someone posted online and then put your credit card into it. This is only safe if you 
retype the address yourself, so you can be sure you're going to a page controlled by 
https://paypal.com/)
```

Comment: Yep, I had the same error, and Paypal customer support gave me the same link to solve the issue. It seems a bit bizarre that Paypal hasn't fixed their new UI to make this work (or has a secret way to bypass their security/detection).

Comment: the New UI doesnt allow my 14 digit discover card to get added, i will try this.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone has an internal error, on your phone or tablet ... Go to Google Chrome in Application Manager -> Clear Cache and hit disable.  Do Not Clear Data, only disable and clear cache, then enable it by going to your History -> Clear all including auto Form Data.  Then go to Your File manager -> Clear All Cache and you're done.

Comment: What does a phone or tablet have to do with the question?

Comment: This is more of a catch-all answer.  Can you confirm that this actually solves the PayPal problem?  Otherwise, this is not of much use.